# How to get contacts sorted by phone number?

Tags: android, cursor, android-contacts

Had tried

```
Cursor c = getContentResolver().query(Data.CONTENT_URI, null, null, null, Phone.NUMBER+" ASC");
```

But apparently the contacts are not sorted correctly.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, I now understand how this works - it is actually ready sorted.

By this:

```
getContentResolver().query(Data.CONTENT_URI, null, null, null, Phone.NUMBER+" ASC");
```

I get:

```
id: 60, data1: +34600000000, mimetype: phone_v2
id: 59, data1: +34698765432, mimetype: phone_v2
id: 59, data1: JohnDavid1 Doe, mimetype: name
id: 60, data1: JohnDavid2 Doe, mimetype: name
```

If I pass `DESC` to `query()`, will get:

```
id: 60, data1: JohnDavid2 Doe, mimetype: name
id: 59, data1: JohnDavid1 Doe, mimetype: name
id: 59, data1: +34698765432, mimetype: phone_v2
id: 60, data1: +34600000000, mimetype: phone_v2
```

So result is actually sorted, though it is not sorting `Contact ID` as I expected.

Answer (score 0):

try with this dude :) best of luck

and this is code of class

```
public class ReadContacts extends AsyncTask<Void, Void, Void>{
    private ListView contactsList;

    private Context cntx;
    private Constant constants;

    static final String[] CONTACTS_SUMMARY_PROJECTION = new String[] {
        Contacts._ID, // 0
        Contacts.DISPLAY_NAME, // 1
        Contacts.STARRED, // 2
        Contacts.TIMES_CONTACTED, // 3
        Contacts.CONTACT_PRESENCE, // 4
        Contacts.PHOTO_ID, // 5
        Contacts.LOOKUP_KEY, // 6
        Contacts.HAS_PHONE_NUMBER, // 7
    };

    private long contactId;
    private String display_name;
    private String phoneNumber;

    private ArrayList<ContactsWrapper>contactWrap = new ArrayList<ContactsWrapper>();
    private HashMap<Long, ArrayList<ContactsWrapper>>map = new HashMap<Long, ArrayList<ContactsWrapper>>();

    private ContactsAdapter adapter;

    private DataController controller;

    public ReadContacts(Context cntx, ListView contactList) {
        // TODO Auto-generated constructor stub
        this.cntx = cntx;
        constants = new Constant();
        this.contactsList = contactList;

        controller = DataController.getInstance(); 
    }

    @Override
    protected void onPreExecute() {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        super.onPreExecute();
        if(!(controller.contactWrapper.size()>0))
             constants.displayProgressDialog(cntx, "Loading Contacts...", "Please Wait");
    }

    @Override
    protected Void doInBackground(Void... params) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub

        if(!(controller.contactWrapper.size()>0))
        {
        try {
            String select = "((" + Contacts.DISPLAY_NAME + " NOTNULL) AND ("
                    + Contacts.HAS_PHONE_NUMBER + "=1) AND ("
                    + Contacts.DISPLAY_NAME + " != '' ))";

            Cursor c = cntx.getContentResolver().query(Contacts.CONTENT_URI, CONTACTS_SUMMARY_PROJECTION, select,
                    null, Contacts.DISPLAY_NAME + " COLLATE LOCALIZED ASC");

            int colorcounter = 0;
            String[] colorcounter_array = { "#91A46B", "#8BB6B5", "#CAA973", "#8DA6C8","#D19B8D"};

            int color_string;
            for(int i=0;i<c.getCount();i++)
            {
//              contactWrap.clear();
                try {
                    contactId = 0;
                    String hasPhone = "";
                    display_name = "";
                    phoneNumber = "";

                    c.moveToPosition(i);

                    contactId =  c.getLong(0);
                    display_name = c.getString(1);
                    hasPhone = c.getString(7);

                    if (hasPhone.equalsIgnoreCase("1"))
                        hasPhone = "true";
                    else
                        hasPhone = "false" ;

                    if (Boolean.parseBoolean(hasPhone)) 
                    {
                        Cursor phones = cntx.getContentResolver().query(ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Phone.CONTENT_URI, null,ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Phone.CONTACT_ID +" = "+ contactId,null, null);
                        while (phones.moveToNext()) 
                        {
                            int indexPhoneType = phones.getColumnIndexOrThrow(Phone.TYPE);
                            String phoneType =  phones.getString(indexPhoneType);

                            phoneNumber = phones.getString(phones.getColumnIndex(ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Phone.NUMBER)); 

                            String lookupKey = phones.getString(phones.getColumnIndex(ContactsContract.Contacts.LOOKUP_KEY));

                            if (colorcounter < 5) 
                            {
                                color_string =Color.parseColor(colorcounter_array[colorcounter]);
                                colorcounter++;
                            } else {
                                colorcounter = 0;
                                color_string =Color.parseColor(colorcounter_array[colorcounter]);
                                colorcounter++;
                            }
                            contactWrap.add(new ContactsWrapper(contactId, display_name, phoneNumber,lookupKey,false,color_string));
                        }
//                      map.put(contactId, new ArrayList<ContactsWrapper>(contactWrap));
                        phones.close();
                    }
                } catch (Exception e) {

                    e.printStackTrace();
                }  
            }
            controller.contactWrapper = contactWrap;
        }
        catch (Exception e) {
            // TODO: handle exception
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        }

        return null;
    }

    @Override
    protected void onPostExecute(Void result) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        super.onPostExecute(result);
        constants.dismissDialog();

        adapter = new ContactsAdapter(cntx);
        contactsList.setAdapter(adapter);
    }

}
```

and this is my contact wrapper class

```
public class ContactsWrapper {

private long contactId;
private String displayName,displayNumber,lookUp;
public boolean checked = true;
int color_string;

public ContactsWrapper(long contactId, String displayName, String displayNumber, String lookUp, boolean checked,int color_string) {
    // TODO Auto-generated constructor stub
    this.contactId = contactId;
    this.displayName = displayName;
    this.displayNumber = displayNumber;
    this.lookUp = lookUp;
    this.checked = checked;
    this.color_string =color_string;
}

public String getLookUp() {
    return lookUp;
}

public int getColor_string() {
    return color_string;
}

public boolean isChecked() {
    return checked;
}

public long getContactId() {
    return contactId;
}

public String getDisplayName() {
    return displayName;
}

public String getDisplayNumber() {
    return displayNumber;
}

public void setChecked(boolean checked) {
    this.checked = checked;
}
}
```

Comment: <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_CONTACTS" />

Comment: Looks like in this code the contacts are not sorted by phone number.